# Angular.js - Digest is not including $scope member changes

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that includes:

```
  newStatusEvent = function(account, eventId, url, deferred, iteration) {
    var checkIteration;
    checkIteration = function(data) {
      if (iteration < CHECK_ITERATIONS && data.Automation.Status !== 'FAILED') {
        iteration++;
        $timeout((function() {
          return newStatusEvent(account, eventId, url, deferred, iteration);
        }), TIME_ITERATION);
      } else {
        deferred.reject('failure');
      }
    };

    url.get().then(function(data) {
      if (data.Automation.Status !== 'COMPLETED') {
        checkIteration(data);
      } else {
        deferred.resolve('complete');
      }
    });
     return deferred.promise;
  };

  runEventCheck = function(account, eventId, modalInstance, state) {
    newStatusEvent(account, eventId, urlBuilder(account, eventId), 
        $q.defer(), 0)
      .then(function() {
           scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state);
      }, function() {
          scopeMutateFailure(modalInstance);
          })["finally"](function() {
          modalEventConfig.disableButtonsForRun = false;
      });
  };

  var modalEventConfig = {
    disableButtonsForRun: false,
    statusBar: false,
    nodeStatus: 'Building',
    statusType: 'warning'
  }

  function scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state){
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //THE SCPOPE DATA MEMBERS THAT ARE CHANGED BUT
    //CURRENT DIGEST() DOES NOT INCLUDE THE CHANGE
    modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';
    modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $timeout(function() {
      scopeMutateResetValues();
      return modalInstance.close();
    }, TIME_CLOSE_MODAL);
    state.forceReload();
  }




  modalEventConfig.scopeMutateStart = scopeMutateStart;

  modalEventConfig.close = scopeMutateResetValues;

  return {
    runEventCheck: runEventCheck,
    modalEventConfig: modalEventConfig
  };
```

---

And here is the controller:

```
angular.module('main.loadbalancer').controller('EditNodeCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, Configuration, LoadBalancerService, NodeService, StatusTrackerService, $state, $q) {
  NodeService.nodeId = $scope.id;
  $q.all([NodeService.getNode(), LoadBalancerService.getLoadBalancer()]).then(function(_arg) {
    var lb, node;
    node = _arg[0], lb = _arg[1];
    $scope.node = node;
    return $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.modalEventConfig.scopeMutateStart();
      return NodeService.updateNode({
        account_number: lb.customer,
        ip: node.address,
        port: node.port_number,
        label: node.label,
        admin_state: node.admin_state,
        comment: node.comment,
        health_strategy: {
          http_request: "" + node.healthMethod + " " + node.healthUri,
          http_response_accept: "200-299"
        },
        vendor_extensions: {}
      }).then(function(eventId) {
        return StatusTrackerService.runEventCheck(lb.customer, eventId,
          $modalInstance, $state);
      });
    }
  });

   $scope.modalEventConfig = StatusTrackerService.modalEventConfig;
```

The issue I am having is in the service. After a successful resolve in `newStatusEvent` and `scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state);` runs... the `modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';` and `modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';` changes aren't reflected in the view.

Normally, this would be because a `digest()` is needed to make angular.js aware of a change. However, I have verified in the stack(chromium debugger) that a digest() was called earlier in the stack and is still in effect when the scope members are mutated in function `scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state);`

What is weird, if I add $rootScope.$apply() after `modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';`...then Angular.js will complain a `digest()` is already in progress...**BUT...the view will successfully update and reflect the new changes** in from the scope members `nodeStatus` and `statusType`. But, obviously this is not the answer/appropriate fix.

So, the question is why isn't the digest() that is currently running from the beginning of the stack(stack from chromium debugger) making angular.js aware of the scope changes for `modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success'` and `modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully'`? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

$scope.modalEventConfig = StatusTrackerService.modalEventConfig; is a synchronous call, you need treat things asynchronously .
You need wait on promise(resolved by service) at calling area also, i.e. in the controller .

Comment: `$scope.modalEventConfig = StatusTrackerService.modalEventConfig;` isn't this a binding by memory reference, not a call? Not sure what you mean about it being async/sync, but I tried placing this in the beginning to no success.

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it.**

function scopeMutateSuccess(modalInstance, state){
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //THE SCPOPE DATA MEMBERS THAT ARE CHANGED BUT
        //CURRENT DIGEST() DOES NOT INCLUDE THE CHANGE
        modalEventConfig.statusType = 'success';
        modalEventConfig.nodeStatus = 'Completed Successfully';
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    $timeout(function() {
      scopeMutateResetValues();
      state.forceReload();
      return modalInstance.close(); 
    }, TIME_CLOSE_MODAL);

  }
```

I am using ui-router and I do a refresh with it useing $delegate. I place `state.forceReload();` in the $timeout...the scope members update as they should. I have no idea why exactly, but I am glad this painful experience has come to a end.